# Configure atom package options from command line?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm writing a shell script I can run on a new machine to install my apps, set preferences, arrange dock, and add homebrew packages, and I'd like to be able to configure atom packages within the script instead of manually. Is this possible?

<strike>Edit: Also I'd like to change the theme from command line, is that possible?</strike>

`cd ~/.atom
touch init.coffee
echo "atom.config.set('core.themes', ['THEME_HERE', 'SYNTAX_THEME_HERE'])" >> init.coffee`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom configuration settings are stored as CSON text in `config.cson` in the `.atom` directory. So, for example, if you ran

```coffeescript
atom.config.set('core.themes', ['THEME_HERE', 'SYNTAX_THEME_HERE'])
```

from inside Atom, in the `config.cson` file, you would see:

```coffeescript
"*":
  core:
    themes: [
      "THEME_HERE"
      "SYNTAX_THEME_HERE"
    ]
```

So, you can write directly to this file from your shell script to configure Atom. You can also change `config.cson` to `config.json` and use JSON (instead of CSON) to configure the editor, which can make it easier to use things like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to work with the file.